# Crop video in Android with FFMpeg

Tags: android-ndk, ffmpeg

I would like to crop my video with FFMpeg. I found how I can do it in console:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter:v "crop=out_w:out_h:x:y" out.mp4
```

I would like to do that in jni C code but I can not find anything on the Internet. Can you tell me how it can be perform in native C code.

Comment: @Syaki : Are done any work around?

Comment: Well I found this: https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java and do every ffmpeg work from my Java code. Eventually I dont need perform any jni code

Comment: @Syaki: Thanks for your link, I tried this and also got success to crop video but It's take show much time to crop. (My video is of 7 secs and 3.95 MB). Have you any workaround for that?